# do a sort on the basis of heightValueStart and animalNumbersRank

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, reactjs

**update 1:** hey updated  logic in sandbox, still its not sorting in ascending order, can you update in my sandbox :( https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-swartz-fh3sb

- I am trying to do a sort on the basis of heightValueStart and animalNumbersRank.
- so I added sortColumn when I map through entire array.
- for some scenario there wont be animalNumbersRank so I added an if condition
- and then I sorted, but still not sorting.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my console, data and code snippet below

```or-tag-here
if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                    //  console.log("response.data--->", response.data);
                    response.data
                        .map(number => {
                            number.sortColumn = '';
                            if (number.animalNumbersRank) {
                                number.sortColumn = number.animalNumbersRank[0].number;

                            }
                            console.log(
                                'number.sortColumn--->',
                                number.sortColumn
                            );
                            console.log(
                                'number.heightValueStart--->',
                                number.heightValueStart
                            );

                            return number;
                        })
                        .sort((a, b) =>
                            a.heightValueStart < b.heightValueStart
                                ? -1
                                : a.heightValueStart > b.heightValueStart
                                    ? 1
                                    : a.sortColumn < b.sortColumn
                                        ? -1
                                        : a.sortColumn > b.sortColumn
                                            ? 1
                                            : 0
                        );

                    res.json(response.data);
                }



console
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->

number.sortColumn---> 76yuwe67
[0] number.heightValueStart---> apple boy
[0] number.sortColumn--->
[0] number.heightValueStart---> apple boy
[0] number.sortColumn---> JTY67256
[0] number.heightValueStart---> apple boy


data
  <!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->
              [
    {"animalrId":11111111111,"lionId":erer,"uiuiuiId":"151856658687700","ddfdfdf":"2018-02-14 19:03:31","category":"wewe5454","organizationName":"apple boy","jioID":"fdkldfkl","jioIDType":"EIN","heightValueStart":"apple boy","formattedjioID":"8989-23892389","lowerOrgName":"apple boy","animalNumbersRank":[{"number":"76yuwe67"}],"dklfkldf":[{"number":"1548267230"}],"jkkklkl":[{"number":"21468096","expired":"Y"}],"sortColumn":"76yuwe67"},

{"animalrId":222222222222,"lionId":232323,"uiuiuiId":"153920398625500","ddfdfdf":"2018-10-10 19:02:45","category":"wewe 2323","organizationName":"apple boy","jioID":"fdkldfkl","jioIDType":"EIN","heightValueStart":"apple boy","formattedjioID":"8989-23892389","lowerOrgName":"apple boy","sortColumn":""},

{"animalrId":33333333333,"lionId":232323,"uiuiuiId":"153920398625500","ddfdfdf":"2018-10-10 19:02:45","category":"wewe 545445","organizationName":"apple boy","jioID":"fdkldfkl","jioIDType":"EIN","heightValueStart":"apple boy","formattedjioID":"8989-23892389","lowerOrgName":"apple boy","animalNumbersRank":[{"number":"JTY67256"}],"dklfkldf":[{"number":"1548267230"}],"jkkklkl":[{"number":"475255"},{"number":"299993436","expired":"Y"}],"sortColumn":"JTY67256"}

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `map` creates a new array, whereas `sort` modifies an existing array.

In essence:

```js
const a = [ 3, 1, 2 ];
const sorted = a.sort();
console.log(`sorted === a`, sorted === a);

const b = [3, 1, 2];
const mapped = a.map(x => x);
console.log(`mapped === b`, mapped === b);
```

The solution is to store the result of the `map` operation, `sort`, and then use the *new* array:

```js
// ...
const mappedData = response.data.map(() => { /* ... */ });
const sortedData = mappedData.sort((a, b) => { /* ... */ });
res.json(sortedData);
/// ...
```

Comment: hey can you update in my code snippet so confusing :(

Comment: Replace the `response.data.map().sort()` by the three lines in the last codeblock.

Comment: hey updated your logic in sandbox, still its not sorting in ascending order, can you update in my sandbox :(  https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-swartz-fh3sb